# Async Task in Fragment1 Blocks Another Async Task on different Fragment2

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I have  single activity App with a drawer menu

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
....
void selectItem(int position) {

          Bundle args = new Bundle();
          args.putInt(PageFragment.ARG_Page_NUMBER, position);
          android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
          android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
          android.support.v4.app.Fragment fragment;
          int ActiveFragmentId = 3;
          if(position == 0 ){
             fragment = new Fragment1();
          } else if( position == 1){   
        fragment = new Fragment2();
    }
}
....
```

and the two fragments Fragment1 and Fragment2 both have async task in them

Now if the Asnc Task in Fragment1 task is started(i.e. hold a break point on onBackground() of the async task in Fragment1 ) and if i switch to Fragment2
the Async Task in Fragment2 will not work until the onPostExceute() of Fragment1 is executed. why is that?

Also getActivity() == null, inside onPostExecute() of Fragmnet1's Async Task, while switching to Fragment2

Answer (score 0):

As they mention in the Order of execution portion [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), the order of execution depends on your API level.

You need to use `task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, params)` instead of just `task.execute(params)`.

Comment: seems to work now(i.e. it's not Blocking), but getActivity() == null, inside onPostExecute() of Fragmnet1's Async Task, while switching to Fragment2

Comment: Well.. If you want to have a background task that lasts longer than the fragment's lifetime, I would recommend you to use a Service. AsyncTasks are meant for short background tasks.

Comment: I want it as long as the Activity is there, not the fragments. so are you saying switching the fragments makes `getActivity() == null` inside the onPostExecute() while replacing the fragments

Answer (score 0):

Try to make synchronized to the two Asynchronous Tasks.